# How to patch a Python 3 module on first import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

Let's say I want to dynamically patch `tkinter.Tk` to make windows stay on top. If I'm certain that following code really uses Tkinter, then I can `import tkinter` before rest of the code and perform necessary updates.

But how to set up the module patching on-demand, ie. only when the rest of the code really imports the module?

I know about `sys.path_hooks` and `sys.meta_path`, but I'm hoping there is something simpler. I don't want to change the finding or loading mechanics, I just want to get hold of the imported module object before it is passed to the importing module.

I don't need to support Python versions older than 3.5.

Comment: Sounds like an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @KlausD. how come?

Comment: Not tested idea: create a module with same name which loads and patches the real module. Adjust PYTHONPATH so the loader is found first.

Comment: You can use ``wrapt``. Easiest to go watch this talk about it, as take too much to explain here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCZmGgtWi3M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose wrapping [`builtins.__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__):

> This function is invoked by the import statement. It can be replaced
>   (by importing the builtins module and assigning to
>   `builtins.__import__`) in order to change semantics of the import
>   statement

```
import builtins
original_import = builtins.__import__

def custom_import(*args, **kw):
    module = original_import(*args, **kw)

    if (module.__name__ == "interesting_module" 
        and not getattr(module, "patch_is_performed", False)):
        patch(module)
        module.patch_is_performed = True

    return module

builtins.__import__ = custom_import
```